# Discord bot repeats 2 times the commands. I use discord.js 11.6.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, discord, discord.js

I have a discord bot, but now it repeats 2 times all the commands, all mi code is in https://github.com/alonely0/verdugo

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation of your problem, including context, the problem, what you have tried, logs you have collected, and code snippets that you think can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure the problem with this is that you have 2 computers or 2 instances running your bot at the same time so that means your bot will also register and listen to the commands twice.. Check all processes where you are running this bot from.