# My djs bot is sending all outputs twice since I switched to replit

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I got a problem here.
I recently decided to move my bot to replit so I can host it 24/7 and now I am having a problem. The bot sends all outputs twice.
Here's the code of my index.js file: https://pastebin.com/Y8Q6mpiw
the `const KeepAlive = require ('./keep_alive.js')` part is so the bot stays online so, that isnt the problem.
[Take a look at the console's pic, you can see two instances of the client once ready console log. Idk how to explain this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoqPI.png)

Comment: Could you share youd `keep_alive.js` file?

Comment: [Could this be the answer to your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60763627/discord-bot-repeats-2-times-the-commands-i-use-discord-js-11-6-2/60770511#60770511)